# What is the lifetime of a delegate created by a lambda in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

Lambdas are nice, as they offer [brevity and locality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873603/whats-the-point-of-a-lambda-expression/5873685#5873685) and [an extra form of encapsulation](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/improved-encapsulation-using-lambdas/). Instead of having to write functions which are only used once you can use a lambda.

While wondering how they worked, I intuitively figured they are **probably only created once**. This inspired me to create a solution which allows [to restrict the scope of a class member beyond private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986023/restricting-scope-of-a-class-member-beyond-private/4986143#4986143) to one particular scope by using the lambda as an identifier of the scope it was created in.

This implementation works, although perhaps overkill (still researching it), proving my assumption to be correct.

A smaller example:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public void Bleh()
    {
        Action action = () => {};
    }

    public void CallBleh()
    {
        Bleh();  // `action` == {Method = {Void <SomeClass>b__0()}}
        Bleh();  // `action` still == {Method = {Void <SomeClass>b__0()}}
    }
}
```

Would the lambda ever return a new instance, or is it guaranteed to always be the same?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Based on your question here and your comment to Jon's answer I think you are confusing multiple things. To make sure it is clear:

- The *method* that backs the delegate for a given lambda is always the same.
- The *method* that backs the delegate for "the same" lambda that appears lexically twice is *permitted* to be the same, but in practice is *not* the same in our implementation.
- The *delegate instance* that is created for a given lambda might or might not always be the same, depending on how smart the compiler is about caching it.

So if you have something like:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    M( ()=>{} )
```

then every time M is called, you get the *same instance* of the delegate because the compiler is smart and generates

```
static void MyAction() {}
static Action DelegateCache = null;

...
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (C.DelegateCache == null) C.DelegateCache = new Action ( C.MyAction )
    M(C.DelegateCache);
}
```

If you have

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    M( ()=>{this.Bar();} )
```

then the compiler generates

```
void MyAction() { this.Bar(); }
...
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    M(new Action(this.MyAction));
}
```

You get a new delegate every time, with the same method.

The compiler is *permitted* to (but in fact does not at this time) generate

```
void MyAction() { this.Bar(); }
Action DelegateCache = null;
...
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    if (this.DelegateCache == null) this.DelegateCache = new Action ( this.MyAction )
    M(this.DelegateCache);
}
```

In that case you would always get the same delegate instance if possible, and every delegate would be backed by the same method.

If you have

```
Action a1 = ()=>{};
Action a2 = ()=>{};
```

Then in practice the compiler generates this as

```
static void MyAction1() {}
static void MyAction2() {}
static Action ActionCache1 = null;
static Action ActionCache2 = null;
...
if (ActionCache1 == null) ActionCache1 = new Action(MyAction1);
Action a1 = ActionCache1;
if (ActionCache2 == null) ActionCache2 = new Action(MyAction2);
Action a2 = ActionCache2;
```

However the compiler is *permitted* to detect that the two lambdas are identical and generate

```
static void MyAction1() {}
static Action ActionCache1 = null;
...
if (ActionCache1 == null) ActionCache1 = new Action(MyAction1);
Action a1 = ActionCache1;
Action a2 = ActionCache1;
```

Is that now clear?

Comment: Very informative! But I'm a little confused by 'permitted'. You mean it's not right now but may be different in the future? I ran the code `Action a1 = () => {}; Action a2 = () => {}; Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(a1, a2));` and this returns false.

Comment: @Jenix: By "permitted" I mean that the author of a C# compiler is permitted to compile your program such that it returns `true` or `false` at the compiler author's discretion. You must not *rely* upon the compiler having one or the other behavlor because this is documented as being allowed to change at any time.

Answer (score 32):

It's not *guaranteed* either way.

From what I remember of the current MS implementation:

- A lambda expression which doesn't capture *any* variables is cached statically
- A lambda expression which only captures "this" *could* be captured on a per-instance basis, but isn't
- A lambda expression which captures a local variable can't be cached
- Two lambda expressions which have the exact same program text *aren't* aliased; in some cases they *could* be, but working out the situations in which they can be would be very complicated
- EDIT: As Eric points out in the comments, you also need to consider *type* arguments being captured for generic methods.

EDIT: The relevant text of the C# 4 spec is in section 6.5.1:

> Conversions of semantically identical anonymous functions with the same (possibly empty) set of captured outer variable instances to the same delegate types are permitted (but not required) to return the same delegate instance. The term semantically identical is used here to mean that execution of the anonymous functions will, in all cases, produce the same effects given the same arguments.

Comment: What exactly do they mean by "the same effects"? Calling `GetCurrentMethod` obviously doesn't have the same effects...

Comment: That sounds about right to me, though things also get a bit tricky if the lambda "captures" a type parameter of a generic method. Even if it makes use of no locals or parameters, it still might not be able to be cached in a static field.

Comment: @Eric: [One of my test cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986023/restricting-scope-of-a-class-member-beyond-private/4986143#4986143) uses `public static Local<TValue> Instance<TScope>( Func<TScope> scope )`, where `() => this` is passed to scope. In this case it is still returning the same delegate.

Comment: I'm disliking the _"(but not required)"_ so much right now, but oh well, I got my answer. :)

Comment: @Steven: I assure you that it is *not* returning the same delegate if you create "()=>this" twice. You're doing something wrong if that's the result you're getting. How are you attempting to compare delegates for equality? **You are aware that delegates have value, not reference equality, right?**

Answer (score 4):

No guarantees.

A quick demo:

```
Action GetAction()
{
    return () => Console.WriteLine("foo");
}
```

Call this twice, do a `ReferenceEquals(a,b)`, and you'll get `true`

```
Action GetAction()
{
    var foo = "foo";
    return () => Console.WriteLine(foo);
}
```

Call this twice, do a `ReferenceEquals(a,b)`, and you'll get `false`

Comment: That confirms Jon's reply: "A lambda expression which captures a local variable can't be cached".

Comment: @Steven As well as, "A lambda expression which doesn't capture any variables is cached statically."

Answer (score 3):

I see Skeet jumped in while I was answering, so I won't belabor that point. One thing I would suggest, to better understand how you are using things, is to get familiar with reverse engineering tools and IL. Take the code sample(s) in question and reverse engineer to IL. It will give you a great amount of information on how the code is working.

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I don't have an "academic answer," more of a practical answer: I could see a compiler optimizing the binary to use the same instance, but I wouldn't ever write code that assumes it's "guaranteed" to be the same instance.

I upvoted you at least, so hopefully someone can give you the academic answer you're looking for.