# How can I dynamically combine a set of LINQ queries at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq, resharper

EDIT:  Trying to make my problem a bit more clear.

I'm trying to build a LINQ expression that is the intersection of several LINQ statements.  Right now, manually I can intersect two statements together and I'm getting the desired result.

```
        var results = 
                context.UserBooleanAttributes.Where(x => x.UserAttributeID == 1 && x.Value).Select(a => a.User)
            .Intersect(
                context.UserBooleanAttributes.Where(y => y.UserAttributeID == 2 && y.Value).Select(b => b.User)
            );

         Assert.Equal(100,results.Count());
```

My goal is to build this dynamically, for example using a for-loop.  Since I am using LINQ, I want to defer execution until I actually call something **results** that forces execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be refactored, to get the multiple lists of users:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<User>> GetListOfListsOfUsers(int xTimes)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= xTimes; i++)
    {
        var someUsers = context.UserBooleanAttributes
                               .Where(x => x.UserAttributeID == i && x.Value == true)
                               .Select(a => a.User);
        yield return someUsers;
    }
}

var listOfListsOfUsers = GetListOfListsOfUsers(xTimes);
```

The problem now becomes [intersection of multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674742/intersection-of-multiple-lists-with-ienumerable-intersect):

```
var intersection = listOfListsOfUsers.Aggregate((previousList, nextList) => previousList.Intersect(nextList));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want a list of `User`:

```
var list = new List<User>();
```

And then you can add each set of results, as you get them:

```
list.AddRange(someUsers);
```

If `User` is a class that you can do an `Intersect` on, and you only want distinct values (which seems to be the case in your code), consider doing it one go, and calling `Distinct()` at the end:

```
var attrIDs = Enumerable.Range(1, xTimes);

list.AddRange(context.UserBooleanAttributes
                     .Where(x => attrIDs.Contains(x.UserAttributeID) && x.Value)
                     .Select(a => a.User)
                     .Distinct());
```

Comment: The problem with AddRange is that it appears to cause the expression to be evaluated.  What I didn't mention in my OP is that I'm using this with EntityFramework, and that after I build my list using Intersect, I want to be able to examine list.ToString() to see the underlying SQL code.

Comment: Updated my question a bit.  The problem with the AddRange is that also is forcing execution of the statement immediately.

Comment: The loop is eliminated in the new query, so the `AddRange()` is redundant. You can just `var list = context.User......Select(a => a.User)`

Comment: Ken, I think I solved it, but would love to see an example

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems going on here.  The first was I needed a way to declare my anonymous variable for use outside of the loop.  I did this by using **IQueryable allBooleansTrue**.  I assigned it a non null value to get Resharper to stop nagging me.  The second problem was I was running into was the famous [closures issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360749/782880).  I solved this using **int copy = i**

```
        IQueryable<User> allBooleansTrue = new List<User>().AsQueryable();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numBools; i++)
        {
            int copy = i; //workaround to prevent closures using reference
            var q = context.UserBooleanAttributes.Where(y => y.UserAttributeID == copy && y.Value)
                .Select(a => a.User);
            if (i == 1)
                allBooleansTrue = q;
            else
                allBooleansTrue = allBooleansTrue.Intersect(q);
```

The first iteration replaces the contents of my outer variable (allBooleansTrue) with the LINQ statement.  Ever other iteration performs an intersection.  A little hacky here, but this appears to work (so far).  I suppose I should be using expression trees, but that's for another day.

Sorry I changed my code around a bit for the original post, but I'm dead tired and copied this from my test class.