# Dictionary with Func as key

Tags: c#, dictionary, func

I am wondering if this is a sane choice of key for a dictionary? What I want to do is use an expression as the key in a dictionary, something like:

```
    var map3 = new Dictionary<Func<int, bool>, int>();
    map3.Add((x) => x % 2 == 0, 1);
    map3.Add((x) => x % 10 == 0, 2);
    // ...

    var key = map3.Keys.SingleOrDefault(f => f(2));
    // key = (x) => x % 2
    // map3[key] = 1
```

The idea being this is a cleaner way than having big if-else or switch statements.

Does this make sense? Will it work? Is there an simpler way?

Comment: In a word; no.  It's often an appropriate value, but as a key I'd avoid it.

Comment: ..that would do my head in maintaining that..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, C# constructs a new delegate instance whenever a lambda is used so you wouldn't be able to use it as a consistent key. Example:

```
        Func<int, int> f = x => x*x + 1;
        Func<int, int> g = x => x*x + 1;
        Console.WriteLine(f.Equals(g)); // prints False
```

This would then make usage awkward as a dictionary key unless you had some other way to always obtain the same instance.

Edit:

Eric Lippert's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6281337/517852) indicates that the compiler is *allowed* to detect the lambdas are the same (although it typically does not). Either way a lambda/delegate makes a poor choice for a key.

Answer (score 9):

Considering the way that you use your map, you will be better off with a `List<Tuple<Func<int,bool>,int>>`, because the order of checking the lambdas will no longer be arbitrary, as in a hash-based dictionary. This approach also lets you skip the lookup step:

```
var map3 = new List<Tuple<Func<int,bool>,int>> {
    new Tuple<Func<int,bool>,int>((x) => x % 2 == 0, 1)
,   new Tuple<Func<int,bool>,int>((x) => x % 10 == 0, 2)
};
var t = map3.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Item1(2));
if (t != null) {
    var v = t.Item2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting @dasblinkenlight's answer with latest syntax:

```
void Main()
{
    var map3 = new List<(Func<int, bool> Key, int Value)> {
        (Key: (x) => x * 2 == 4, Value: 1),
        (Key: (x) => x * 10 == 100, Value: 2)
    };

    var result = map3.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Key(10));
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
}
```

When `Key` evaluates to a Func which is not there on the `List` `SingleOrDefault` returns  an element with key null and value 0.

`Key` and `Value` above are for readability, they can be removed and in that case `result.Intem2` will produce output