# Why does a GC after a LINQ query free the WhereListIterator but not the Func representing the condition?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, garbage-collection

I was looking at the memory impact of a simple LINQ query and noticed that the LINQ query created 2 extra objects of types `Enumerable+WhereListIterator<Int32>` and `Func<Int32, Boolean>`.

The code used is this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Setting baseline snapshot
    var list1 = new List<int> { 4862, 6541, 7841 };
    var list2 = new List<int>(list1.Count);
    var list3 = new List<int>(list1.Count);

    // First snapshot: LINQ usage
    list2.AddRange(list1.Where(item => item > 5000 && item < 7000));

    // Second snapshot: foreach-loop
    foreach (var item in list1)
    {
        if (item > 5000 && item < 7000)
        {
            list3.Add(item);
        }
    }

    // End gather
    Console.Read();
}
```

At the snapshot after the `foreach` loop I notice that the `Enumerable+WhereListIterator<Int32>` object is garbage collected but the `Func<Int32, Boolean>` is still in memory.

Why is this still kept around? At that point in time (at the `Console.Read` statement) I don't think anything is still referencing it and a GC has been forced by the profiler (which is why the iterator is collected).

Note: collecting additional snapshots does not alter how many objects are freed so it's not a matter of the `Func` being marked for collection for the next run.

Comment: Comment on reopening the question: although the linked question is definitely related, this question asks about a specific case, and provides a demo to demonstrate what is going on.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight fair enough, let's keep it open then.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason the lambda is not GC-ed is the structure of the lambda itself:

```
item => item > 5000 && item < 7000
```

This lambda does not *capture* anything, meaning that it can be compiled once, and reused forever. C# discovers this, and takes advantage of lambdas like that by caching them statically to improve performance.

Had your lambda captured a variable from its context, it would have been garbage collected when it is no longer needed.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6280711/335858) for more information on lambda lifetime in .NET.

Comment: Perfect, that and the linked answers explain everything.